# Satellites with higher revisit frequency

Tags: satellite

Sun-Synchronous orbit has a 16 day revisit. Geo synchronous though further away, observe the same spot on earth, and can provide data with higher frequency.
Most earth observation satellites that share data publically I know are in sun-synchronous orbit except GOES (east and west), which provides data every 5 mins.

I am looking for satellites that can provide data with higher frequency. Are there other satellites which provide data at higher frequency? (We don't care about what location they are observing on earth)

Comment: If I understand correctly, 5 minutes is too slow for your needs?

Comment: 5 mins is good. 16 days is too slow  (or 6 days in case of pair of satellites).
Basically we want more than a single visit per day

Comment: Seems like GOES ought to do the job!

Comment: sorry - I want to know of other sources. I am familiar with GOES.